# How to Fix “No route to host” SSH Error in Debian

Tags: linux, debian

I have install Debian 9. It's a clean installation.

When trying to connect at my server with putty port 22 the following error is displayed:

> No route to host

SSH server is running.

Please can you help me?

Comment: Check if the debian server is running any firewall

Comment: How can i check this ? It's new install, i don't have install any package

Comment: Did you check your network settings? Is this the only server you can't reach?

Comment: Im noob in linux it's my first install. And i have open port on my Box.

I can connect in local but not out of my network

Comment: How did you set up your network? Static address or DHCP?

Comment: DHCP and my local ip is 192.168.1.239

Comment: Does `ip route` show your router's address for the default route (for example, `default via 192.168.1.1`)? In fact, please add `ip route` to your question details for us.

Comment: My internet box have ip 192.168.1.1

Comment: Please update your question with the requested information. It is important to see the IP address of both the local and the remote systems, and the routing information on the local machine. Do _not_ add this info in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, it's difficult to tell from the question, but if you are coming to your newly installed box from a PC PuTTY session, you may not have the address of your Debian box set correctly.  Double check the address and make sure that the address you assigned to the Linux box is in the range of your network.

If you are having trouble going out from your Linux box and getting "No route to host,", then your default gateway or route is not set correctly.  On the local box type the command "route" and see what it says.

The specifics of setting the default route can vary from one system to another, but this wiki is an elementary level guide:  https://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Change-the-Default-Gateway-in-Linux

Comment: I have one error when i type **route** in terminal.

`root@debian-9:/home/user# route
bash: route : command not found`

Comment: i have enter route... look i have edit my comment

Comment: /usr/sbin/route

Comment: sorry don't work

Comment: Unless Debian uses another command (I don't think it does), then I suspect something failed in your installation.  It may be simpler in the long run to go back to the start and step through the installation from the beginning.  That's as much as I can offer.

Comment: It's one new install, i don't have change config... all is by default

Comment: cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.factory-defaults && sed -i "s/#Port 22/Port 22122/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config ; systemctl restart sshd.service

**Work for debian 9 but not for debian 8**

Answer (score 1):

I've had SSH port not turned by default. Do you have a panel that you can access and check? Like what a VPS provider might offer.

```
sudo systemctl status ssh
```

With a VPS panel access you can install.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then make sure server is running

```
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

To login to your server

```
ssh user@45.67.89.10
```

You'll find lots of recommendations on hardening SSH. I recommend changing SSH Port to something like 22122

```
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.factory-defaults && sed -i "s/#Port 22/Port 22122/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config ; systemctl restart sshd.service
```

Login with

```
ssh -p 22122 user@45.67.89.10
```

OR just generate and add SSH Key to your server. Plenty of guides and better than using password.

Comment: Sorry Chris, login command is for Linux. I guess if you're using Putty you're on a Windows system. So just change GUI Port once you get logged in.